# How to remove empty spaces Notepad++ using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a textfile contains lines with below:

```
IP              Ports           
1.160.0.224     8080            
1.160.1.49      8080            
1.160.1.70      8080            
1.160.1.170     8080            
1.160.1.239     8080
```

I want to use notepad++ regex to remove all empty space and just leave the IP:PORT.

For example below:

```
1.160.0.224:8080
1.160.1.49:8080
1.160.1.70:8080
1.160.1.170:8080
1.160.1.239:8080
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Find:**

```
(\d)\s+(\d+)\s+
```

**Replace:**

```
$1:$2\r\n
```

This solution takes into account that you may have a header at the top of your table which you don't want modified during the replacement.  It also takes into account that your original data appears to have extra whitespace after the port number `8080`.

Here is a screen capture showing you what your find/replace window should look like:

[image]

Comment: Work perfectly, thank you all for your prompt response. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use this search regexp `\s+` (one or more empty characters)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\s+` to match one or more whitespace, to use notepad++, you can replace based on the "regular expression", but you still need to manually replace by "Find Next" and "Replace" one by one to choose where you want to repalce.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Notepad++ UI, but your pattern should be  `*` (a space followed by `*`), and you replacement should be `:`

Answer (score 1):

Find--> `(\s*)(.\*?)(\s*)`   and   ReplaceWith--> `\2`

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: perfect solution for my needs